# How to center the child view but keep aspect ratio in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using `ConstraintLayout` that contains child view.
I want this child view centered but keeping aspect ratio.

**Layout (landscape) variant:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/previewParent"
    tools:context=".PeakerActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/flexbox2">


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adding `android:gravity="center"` has no effect, child view is still not centered.

[image: Result]

**Edit**: Added image, as you see, left purple side is greater than right side.

Comment: Looks like you set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in your parent layout. Try setting it to true.

Comment: Setting to true dont have any effect.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in the code disables it. It is easier to see it using layout inspector in android studio to check if the app root view overlaps with status bar and/or navigation bar.

Comment: Sure, i am not disable it, but maybe some lib, i ll try tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, with `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` layout attribute by keeping it half (0.5).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/previewParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:id="@+id/flexbox2"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**[Bias](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#centering-positioning-and-bias)**

The default when encountering such opposite constraints is to center the widget; but you can tweak the positioning to favor one side over another using the bias attributes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you provided, it seems that your layout extends below the navigation bar or does not extend above the status bar. To troubleshoot this issue, consider adding a TextView at both the bottom and top of your ConstraintLayout. This will help you verify if the positioning is correct.